# How to iterate and flatten each column in one groupby value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to firstly group different rows, if their first item in the row is the same, then flatten each columns in one group into a list.

My initial dataframe:

[image]

And my target:

[image]

The problem is that I cannot use simply `df.groupby('key').apply(list)` cause it will flatten columns `val1` and `v`al2 together`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

Use `agg` instead of `apply`:

```
df.groupby('key').agg(list)
```

Output:

```
    key       val1       val2
0  key1  [1, 2, 5]  [2, 3, 6]
```